# Is this the right way to get odometry information in stageros?

Tags: ros, navigation, odometry, stageros, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm simulating robots in stageros and I want to use stageros' odom topic to get the current position of the robot. This is how my code looks:

```
}
    // In a constructor
    RobotOdometry_sub = n.subscribe<nav_msgs::Odometry>("robot_0/odom",1000,&Robot::ReceiveOdometry,this);
}
void Robot::ReceiveOdometry(nav_msgs::Odometry msg)
{
    //This is the call back function to process odometry messages coming from Stage.    
    px = initialX + msg.pose.pose.position.x;
    py = initialY + msg.pose.pose.position.y;
    ptheta = initialTheta + angles::normalize_angle_positive(asin(msg.pose.pose.orientation.z) * 2);

    while (ptheta > 2 * M_PI)
    {
        ptheta -= 2 * M_PI;
    }
    while (ptheta < 0)
    {
        ptheta += 2 * M_PI;
    }
}
```

For some reason though the px and py values are wrong whenever I check them and they don't match up with the position of the robot in the stageros world. Is this not the right way to get the current pose of a position model in stageros? Do I need to do something else?

Please help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41701/is-this-the-right-way-to-get-odometry-information-in-stageros?/) by [Clefairy](https://answers.ros.org/users/3004/clefairy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-08-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-08-17**:
How do the values px and py look like and what should they be? Did you try with initialX and initialY set to 0? Btw. for calculating theta, you should probably use [tf::getYaw](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/tf/html/namespacetf.html#33e93f413622e296d0a2a93b252bbb4b).

**Comment by [Clefairy](https://answers.ros.org/users/3004/clefairy/) on 2012-08-17**:
px and py are 9.9 and 10.1 when they are 5.7 and 12.4 in the world. initialX and initialY were set to 15 and 20. Doesn't seem to work when it's set to 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The /odom topic usually specifies the estimated position of the robot relative to its starting position and not relative to the map. If you want to obtain the position of your robot in the map, you will have to listen on a topic of your (fake) localization (give you are running localization). I don't know for Stage, but usually this should e.g. be /amcl_pose (if you use ROS amcl localization).

Alternatively you can query TF for a transform between the /base_link frame of your robot and the /map-frame (again assuming you run a localization).

---

Originally posted by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) with karma: 2108 on 2012-08-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) on 2012-08-17**:
ah I see, you are somehow already considering the Initial-pose of the robot... but maybe it would make sense anyway to use the tf transforms instead of the Odometry message...

**Comment by [Clefairy](https://answers.ros.org/users/3004/clefairy/) on 2012-08-17**:
I'm not that familiar with localization. I've read the amcl ROS wiki and tried subscribing to amcl_pose before but it didn't seem to work because when I type "rosrun amcl amcl scan:=base_scan", it just says "Request for map failed; trying again...".

**Comment by [Clefairy](https://answers.ros.org/users/3004/clefairy/) on 2012-08-17**:
I couldn't figure it out because there's so little documentation other than the ROS wiki. Is there a procedure I'm supposed to follow to get it to work?

**Comment by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) on 2012-08-17**:
AMCL needs a map of your environment i.e. a map-server must be running and a map loaded, otherwise localization will not work... But I'm not sure if your stage-environment includes a 2D-gridmap since i only used stageros 2 years ago...